# Search scope in MongoDB, want subelement, not entire document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have MongoDB documents with rather complex structure:

Top level **organisation** (one element)

dozens of attributes, among interesting are **founders** and **managers**

**founders** - is a list of founders, each having lastname, firstname, patronym (and other attributes)

Same with **managers** - list of elements with lastname, firstname, patronym (and other attributes)

I want to search in one query by lastname + firstname + patronym combo.
Query should support multiple lastnames, firstnames, patronyms (with the help of $in) (that's for different names of one person, i.e. jon, john, johny)

My current code returns organisations with lastname + firstname + patronym combo inside ORGANISATION, but I need lastname + firstname + patronym combo inside PERSON. Is it possible? Would be grateful even for right direction, not code. As far as I understand, $elemMatch will not help me or it would be very cumbersome query? Maybe a bit cleaner options do exist?

I've already tried to change

```
List<BasicDBObject> args
```

for

```
BasicDBObject name
```

and populate it with append. Nothing changed.

My code:

```
List<BasicDBObject> args = new ArrayList<>();
args.add(new BasicDBObject("founders.typeperson.person.lastname", new BasicDBObject("$in", request.getLastnames())));
args.add(new BasicDBObject("founders.typeperson.person.firstname", new BasicDBObject("$in", request.getFirstnames())));
args.add(new BasicDBObject("founders.typeperson.person.patronym", new BasicDBObject("$in", request.getPatronyms())));
argsListUL.add(new BasicDBObject("$and", args));

result = collection.find(new BasicDBObject("$or", argsListUL)).into(new ArrayList<Document>());
```

Actually, there are much more DBObjects in final argsListUL, but I've removed that code for simplicity.

**update**
Trying to constuct simplest query in shell with $elemMatch. Strange, but it doesn't work:

```
db.collection.find( { "founders.typeperson.person": { $elemMatch: { "lastname": "bla" , "firstname": "bla","patronym" : "bla"  } } } ).pretty()
```

gets 0 results. While combination of lastname + firstname + patronym exists in DB.

Another note: the database is 500GB in size, so I think $elemMatch in projection will be way too slow.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try sharing your database scheme. Your database scheme is unclear from your quetion.

Though from what I understand, you have a data structure as below. Though if the structure or requirement is any different, I'll update the answer.

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId(''),
  "organization": "x",
  founders: [
    {
      lastname: 'a'
      firstname: 'a',
      patronym: 'a'
    },
    {
      lastname: 'b'
      firstname: 'b',
      patronym: 'b'
    }
  ],
  managers: [
    {
      {
        lastname: 'c'
        firstname: 'c',
        patronym: 'c'
      },
      {
        lastname: 'd'
        firstname: 'd',
        patronym: 'd'
      }
    }
  ]

}
```

I can suggest that you look into the aggregation pipeline.

The query that you can use to get just subdocuments will be:-

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    'organization': '<name>'
  }
}, {
  $unwind: '$managers'
}, {
  $unwind: '$founders'
}, {
  $match: {

    $or: [{
      $or: [{
        "managers.lastname": {
          $regex: 'searchString',
          $options: 'i'
        }
      }, {
        "managers.firstname": {
          $regex: 'searchString',
          $options: 'i'
        }
      }, {
        "managers.patronym": {
          $regex: 'searchString',
          $options: 'i'
        }
      }]
    }, {
      $or: [{
        "founders.lastname": {
          $regex: 'searchString',
          $options: 'i'
        }
      }, {
        "founders.firstname": {
          $regex: 'searchString',
          $options: 'i'
        }
      }, {
        "founders.patronym": {
          $regex: 'searchString',
          $options: 'i'
        }
      }]
    }]
  }
}, {
  $group: {
    "_id": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "organization": "$organization",
    },
    "founders": {
      "$push": '$founders'
    }, 
    "managers": {
      "$push": '$managers'
    }
  }
}, {
  $project: {
    "_id": 0,
    "founders": 1,
    "managers" 1
  }
}])
```

If the data to be stored in the founders & managers subdocument is not large, the $regex query will not result into any performance bottleneck.

Comment: Thank you for answering. You are generally right about structure, but my search is not on organisation name, but on fullname combination. And dataset is rather huge, 500GB: 60mln organisations (each having from 1 to 10000 founders). Right now I'm thinking - the fastest way will be to merge fullname to ONE field. This way it will work fast.

Comment: Alright so what you want is to search over the founders and managers of those 60 million orgs at a time. Have you sharded your database?